# How to overwrite info in txt file name already exists

Tags: python, overwrite, txt

I have a program that creates a randomly generated password for whatever website you put. WhatI'd like if possible is if the user puts Amazon and it outputs a password and later inputs Amazon again that it will not duplicate Amazon in the text file but rather update the previously entered password with the new one. I'm not sure if it's possible or if it will always just append to my list.

```
import random
import string
# name of website we're creating the password for
website = input("What website are you creating a password for? ").capitalize()
def char_length():
    # makes it so this part will repeat
    while True:
        length = input("How many characters would you like your password to be? ")
        if length.isdigit() and 0 < int(length) < 51:
            return int(length)
        else:
            print('Response must be a number between 0 and 50')

def random_pass(length):
    while True:
        spec_char = input("Would you like special characters in your password y/n? ").lower()
        if spec_char == "y":
            characters =  string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation
            password = ''.join(random.choice(characters) for i in range(length))
            print("Your password for", website, "is:", password)
            return password
        elif spec_char == "n":
            characters = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for i in range(length))
            print("Your password for", website, "is:", characters)
            return characters
        else:
            print("Please only type 'Yes' or 'No'.")

random_pass(char_length())

file = open("password.txt", "a+")
webname = file.write(website)
file.write(": ")
new_pass = file.write(random_pass(char_length()))
file.write("\n")
print(webname)
print(new_pass)
file.close()
```

I've tried doing it a few different ways myself but i'm only a month into learning python so I don't know exactly how to approach this.

Comment: Of course you can, you just have to check through the file first.  Let me make a suggestion: store your usernames in JSON as a dictionary with website as the key.  Now you can read the whole dictionary using `json.load`, you can do `if website in data:` to see if the name already exists, and you can use `json.dump` to write it back to file.

Comment: Thanks Tim, unfortunately I'm not too familiar with JSON. I do know dictionaries! I'll youtube some videos on it and see what I can come up with.

Comment: Great suggestion from @TimRoberts, python and json are a perfect match. You can as well utilize pickle module to learn something new but json are most popular format for data transfer(at least in web), so it is a must to know basics. Also consider hashing your randomly generated password as some of next feature.

Comment: The nice thing about JSON is you don't have to worry about the formatting.  You just create and maintain your dictionary.  `json.dump` will automatically write it out as JSON, and `json.load` will convert it back to a dictionary.